# Can electric field be restricted?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance

In high school physics, the electric field between a pair of NOT INFINTE paralle plate electrodes exists only between the plates, but now we know there are electric field lines curved out from the edge of the anode plate to the edge of the cathode plate. I am thinking, is there a way to restrict the location of the field so that it only exists at the orientation we want them to? (e.g. so that the electric field can only be detected between the parallel plate electrodes, but not its immediate surroundings)

Comment: Precision capacitors have guard rings to try and reduce edge effects.

Answer (score 0):

The picture below shows how the electric field of a capacitor looks like.

[image]

As you can see, besides the field between the plates and near the edges of the plates, there is also a field at points A and B, in the middle of the plates.

This field is there because not all, but only the majority of the surface charges are located on the inside surfaces of the plates, i.e., some charges are located on the outside surfaces of the plates.

The field at points A and B is going to be present as long as the capacitor is charged to some non-zero voltage. If this field was not present, the potential of the outside surfaces and therefore the voltage between them or the voltage on the capacitor would be zero.

So, there is no way the field lines of a capacitor with finite plates could be restricted to the space between the plates.

Comment: If there are two paralle plate capacitator put paralle together like this ==, would the electric field between them being "bented" inward by each other's field?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, than the answer is yes. In the limit, when two parallel capacitors merge, there won't be any bending.